# How to programmatically deny editing the headers and footers?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am creating a word template. My users must not be able to edit the headers.

AFAIK It's not possible to just lock the header so I guess I need to use VBA. However, I haven't found anything related to that. I guess it is possible by handling a specific event, but I couldn't find anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can lock the headers by using "Restrict Editing"  under developers tab.

Restrict Editing -> editing restrictions -> check allow only this type of editing -> change the drop down to no changes read only -> cntrl + A to select the body -> under exceptions click every one -> start enforcement (put in a password)

so the users will only be able to edit the body

Comment: I didn't know I could do it like that. Awesome :) Thanks!